# How can I prevent a commit reverting back to an old commit in the main branch when switching branches - Git?

Tags: git, github, commit

Whenever I create a new branch in Github Desktop and switch to it there, my local files and project revert to the last commit in main and files get deleted.

I have been working on other branches off of main and the main is commits behind on purpose.

How can I prevent this and why is it happening? I just want to create a new branch or switch branch on Github desktop without affecting my local projects and have it apply changes automatically.

Comment: can you add screenshot? my first thought is that either you have nested gits or uncommited changes in other branches

Comment: @smcrowley Hey, thanks, no uncommitted changes waiting in my GH Desktop app. But main is behind on the updates and files committed as I wanted to commit them in other branches that go off main. I'm only using Github Desktop to commit and push

Comment: The GitHub Desktop app is not Git; you should not expect it to behave the way Git does. Pick one to learn and use at a time. You're asking about Git and GItHub, rather than GitHub Desktop, based on your tags, but you're asking about GitHub Desktop (the app), based on your text!